# How Spring encodePassword with salt

Tags: spring, spring-security, md5, salt

I introduce Spring security for a web application. First I have my authentication manager as follows.

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder hash='md5'>
        </password-encoder> 
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

For tesing I'm going to use '1' as both username and password. I use a online md5 hash generator and I got 'c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b' for md5(1). Login works fine with this configuration. The I wanted to try salt and I modify authentication manager as follows.

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder hash='md5'>
            <salt-source user-property="username"/>
        </password-encoder> 
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

So as I read in web how salt used is like hash(salt + password). So using the same tool I hash '11' then got hash value '6512bd43d9caa6e02c990b0a82652dca'. I update the database with that value. But now login fail with error thrown 'Caused : Bad credentials'. Which means password didn't match with the database. So my question is does that mean Spring use a different way for salting?

Comment: Use [BCrypt](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8528804/241990). It is more secure and the salting takes care of itself. MD5 is not really a good choice for hashing passwords.

Comment: Should try that. Thanks Luke

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using spring security, you can think of using `PasswordEncoder` bean.

```
<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
</beans:bean>
```

And your authentication manager would be something like (change code ) :

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
            <salt-source user-property="username"/>
        <password-encoder/>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
    </authentication-provider>
 </authentication-manager>
```

Visit [Spring Security Custom Authentication and Password Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658853/spring-security-custom-authentication-and-password-encoding) & [Spring Security:password encoding in DB and in applicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521251/spring-securitypassword-encoding-in-db-and-in-applicationconext) to know more.

Comment: Using property "hash" does the same isn't it? I think it is same as explicitly creating a bean. Injecting a org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder as the PasswordEncoder do easily as following right?

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder hash="sha">
            <salt-source user-property="username"/>
        <password-encoder/>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
    </authentication-provider>
 </authentication-manager>

Answer (score 0):

Damn anyway Spring salting method is different. User following Java code to calculate hash with salt.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Md5PasswordEncoder md5 = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
    String hash = md5.encodePassword("1", "1");
    System.out.println(hash);
}
```

I got '6a8a1f634e38d30e87b450899b31f810' as encrypted password(Different right??). Then I insert it to the database and try my application login. Vola!!! login succeed.